# How do I connect the Graphics Capture API to IMFSinkWriter

Tags: winapi, directx, ms-media-foundation, c++-winrt, dxgi

I am attempting to write some code that connects the `Windows::Graphics::Capture` API to `IMFSinkWriter` in order to capture the desktop to an MP4 file. I find that the `IMFSinkWriter` `WriteSample` function always returns 0x80070057 and I'm trying to understand why. I suspect there is a somewhat obvious mistake as I am not extremely familiar with COM, WinRT, DirectX, etc. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

// XXX workaround bug in platform headers where this has a circular declaration
#include "winrt/base.h"
namespace winrt::impl
{
    template <typename Async>
    auto wait_for(Async const& async, Windows::Foundation::TimeSpan const& timeout);
}
// XXX

#include <dxgi.h>
#include <inspectable.h>
#include <dxgi1_2.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#include <codecapi.h>
#include <strmif.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.System.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Graphics.Capture.h>
#include <windows.graphics.capture.interop.h>
#include <windows.graphics.directx.direct3d11.interop.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Mfuuid.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Mfplat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfreadwrite.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Mf.lib")


winrt::com_ptr<IMFSinkWriter> sinkWriter;
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point firstFrameTime;
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point lastFrameTime;
bool recordedFirstFrame = false;

void OnFrameArrived(winrt::Windows::Graphics::Capture::Direct3D11CaptureFramePool const& sender, winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const &) {
    winrt::Windows::Graphics::Capture::Direct3D11CaptureFrame frame = sender.TryGetNextFrame();
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point frameTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    LONGLONG duration = 0;
    LONGLONG frametime100ns;
    if (!recordedFirstFrame) {
        recordedFirstFrame = true;
        firstFrameTime = frameTime;
        frametime100ns = 0;
    }
    else {
        frametime100ns = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - firstFrameTime).count() / 100;
        duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(frameTime - lastFrameTime).count();
    }
    auto surface = frame.Surface();
    auto access = surface.as<Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DDxgiInterfaceAccess>();
    winrt::com_ptr<ID3D11Texture2D> texture;
    winrt::check_hresult(access->GetInterface(winrt::guid_of<ID3D11Texture2D>(), texture.put_void()));

    IMFMediaBuffer* buffer;
    MFCreateDXGISurfaceBuffer(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), texture.get(), 0, FALSE, &buffer);


    IMFSample *sample;
    winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateSample(&sample));
    HRESULT hr = sample->AddBuffer(buffer);
    printf("add buffer! %x\n", hr);

    hr = sample->SetSampleTime(frametime100ns);
    printf("set sample time (%lld) %d\n", frametime100ns, hr);
    hr = sample->SetSampleDuration(duration);
    printf("set sample duration (%lld) %d\n", duration, hr);

    hr = sinkWriter->WriteSample(0 /* video stream index */, sample);
    printf("wrote sample %x\n", hr);

    lastFrameTime = frameTime;
}


int main()
{  
    winrt::init_apartment(winrt::apartment_type::multi_threaded);
    winrt::check_hresult(MFStartup(MF_VERSION, MFSTARTUP_NOSOCKET));

    // get a list of monitor handles
    std::vector<HMONITOR> monitors;
    EnumDisplayMonitors(
        nullptr, nullptr,
        [](HMONITOR hmon, HDC, LPRECT, LPARAM lparam) {
            auto& monitors = *reinterpret_cast<std::vector<HMONITOR>*>(lparam);
            monitors.push_back(hmon);
            return TRUE;
        },
        reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&monitors)
     );

     //get GraphicsCaptureItem for first monitor
     auto interop_factory = winrt::get_activation_factory<winrt::Windows::Graphics::Capture::GraphicsCaptureItem, IGraphicsCaptureItemInterop>();
     winrt::Windows::Graphics::Capture::GraphicsCaptureItem item = { nullptr };
     winrt::check_hresult(
        interop_factory->CreateForMonitor(
        monitors[0],
            winrt::guid_of<ABI::Windows::Graphics::Capture::IGraphicsCaptureItem>(),
            winrt::put_abi(item)
        )
     );

     // Create Direct 3D Device
     winrt::com_ptr<ID3D11Device> d3dDevice;
     winrt::check_hresult(D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr, D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT,
        nullptr, 0, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, d3dDevice.put(), nullptr, nullptr));


     winrt::Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DDevice device;
     const auto dxgiDevice = d3dDevice.as<IDXGIDevice>();
     {
        winrt::com_ptr<::IInspectable> inspectable;
        winrt::check_hresult(CreateDirect3D11DeviceFromDXGIDevice(dxgiDevice.get(), inspectable.put()));
        device = inspectable.as<winrt::Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11::IDirect3DDevice>();
     }


     auto idxgiDevice2 = dxgiDevice.as<IDXGIDevice2>();
     winrt::com_ptr<IDXGIAdapter> adapter;
     winrt::check_hresult(idxgiDevice2->GetParent(winrt::guid_of<IDXGIAdapter>(), adapter.put_void()));
     winrt::com_ptr<IDXGIFactory2> factory;
     winrt::check_hresult(adapter->GetParent(winrt::guid_of<IDXGIFactory2>(), factory.put_void()));

     ID3D11DeviceContext* d3dContext = nullptr;
     d3dDevice->GetImmediateContext(&d3dContext);


    // setup swap chain
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 desc = {};
    desc.Width = static_cast<uint32_t>(item.Size().Width);
    desc.Height = static_cast<uint32_t>(item.Size().Height);
    desc.Format = static_cast<DXGI_FORMAT>(winrt::Windows::Graphics::DirectX::DirectXPixelFormat::R16G16B16A16Float);
    desc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    desc.BufferCount = 2;
    desc.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH;
    desc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL;
    desc.AlphaMode = DXGI_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED;
    winrt::com_ptr<IDXGISwapChain1> swapchain;
    winrt::check_hresult(factory->CreateSwapChainForComposition(d3dDevice.get(), &desc, nullptr, swapchain.put()));

    auto framepool = winrt::Windows::Graphics::Capture::Direct3D11CaptureFramePool::CreateFreeThreaded(device, winrt::Windows::Graphics::DirectX::DirectXPixelFormat::R16G16B16A16Float, 2, item.Size());
    auto session = framepool.CreateCaptureSession(item);
    framepool.FrameArrived(OnFrameArrived);

    //Setup MF output stream
    winrt::com_ptr<IMFDXGIDeviceManager> devManager;
    UINT resetToken;
    winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateDXGIDeviceManager(&resetToken, devManager.put()));
    winrt::check_hresult(devManager->ResetDevice(d3dDevice.get(), resetToken));
    winrt::com_ptr<IMFByteStream> outputStream;
    winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateFile(MF_ACCESSMODE_READWRITE, MF_OPENMODE_DELETE_IF_EXIST, MF_FILEFLAGS_NONE, L"C:\\test.mp4", outputStream.put()));

    //configure MF output media type
    winrt::com_ptr<IMFMediaType> videoMediaType;
    //winrt::com_ptr<IMFMediaType> audioMediaType;

    //for video
    winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateMediaType(videoMediaType.put()));
    winrt::check_hresult(videoMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video));
    winrt::check_hresult(videoMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264));
    winrt::check_hresult(videoMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, 2000000));
    winrt::check_hresult(videoMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive));
    winrt::check_hresult(videoMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_MPEG2_PROFILE, eAVEncH264VProfile_Main));
    winrt::check_hresult(videoMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_YUV_MATRIX, MFVideoTransferMatrix_BT601));
    winrt::check_hresult(MFSetAttributeSize(videoMediaType.get(), MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, item.Size().Width, item.Size().Height));
    winrt::check_hresult(MFSetAttributeRatio(videoMediaType.get(), MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 30, 1));
    winrt::check_hresult(MFSetAttributeRatio(videoMediaType.get(), MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1));

    //Creates a streaming writer
    winrt::com_ptr<IMFMediaSink> mp4StreamSink;
    winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateMPEG4MediaSink(outputStream.get(), videoMediaType.get(), NULL, mp4StreamSink.put()));

    //setup MF Input stream
    winrt::com_ptr<IMFMediaType> inputVideoMediaType;

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    GUID majortype = { 0 };
    MFRatio par = { 0 };

    hr = videoMediaType->GetMajorType(&majortype);
    if (majortype != MFMediaType_Video)
    {
        throw new winrt::hresult_invalid_argument();
    }
    // Create a new media type and copy over all of the items.
    // This ensures that extended color information is retained.
    winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateMediaType(inputVideoMediaType.put()));
    winrt::check_hresult(videoMediaType->CopyAllItems(inputVideoMediaType.get()));
    // Set the subtype.
    winrt::check_hresult(inputVideoMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_ARGB32));
    // Uncompressed means all samples are independent.
    winrt::check_hresult(inputVideoMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_ALL_SAMPLES_INDEPENDENT, TRUE));
    // Fix up PAR if not set on the original type.
    hr = MFGetAttributeRatio(
        inputVideoMediaType.get(),
        MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO,
        (UINT32*)&par.Numerator,
        (UINT32*)&par.Denominator
    );
    // Default to square pixels.
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        winrt::check_hresult(MFSetAttributeRatio(
            inputVideoMediaType.get(),
            MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO,
            1, 1
        ));
    }

    winrt::check_hresult(MFSetAttributeSize(inputVideoMediaType.get(), MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, item.Size().Width, item.Size().Height));
    inputVideoMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_VIDEO_ROTATION, MFVideoRotationFormat_0); //XXX where do we get the rotation from?

    winrt::com_ptr<IMFAttributes> attributes;
    winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateAttributes(attributes.put(), 6));
    winrt::check_hresult(attributes->SetGUID(MF_TRANSCODE_CONTAINERTYPE, MFTranscodeContainerType_MPEG4));
    winrt::check_hresult(attributes->SetUINT32(MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS, 1));
    winrt::check_hresult(attributes->SetUINT32(MF_MPEG4SINK_MOOV_BEFORE_MDAT, 1));
    winrt::check_hresult(attributes->SetUINT32(MF_LOW_LATENCY, FALSE)); ///XXX should we?
    winrt::check_hresult(attributes->SetUINT32(MF_SINK_WRITER_DISABLE_THROTTLING, FALSE)); //XX shuold we?
    // Add device manager to attributes. This enables hardware encoding.
    winrt::check_hresult(attributes->SetUnknown(MF_SINK_WRITER_D3D_MANAGER, devManager.get()));

    //winrt::com_ptr<IMFSinkWriter> sinkWriter;
    winrt::check_hresult(MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink(mp4StreamSink.get(), attributes.get(), sinkWriter.put()));
    sinkWriter->SetInputMediaType(0, inputVideoMediaType.get(), nullptr);
 
    winrt::com_ptr<ICodecAPI> encoder;
    sinkWriter->GetServiceForStream(0 /* video stream index */, GUID_NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(encoder.put()));
    VARIANT var;
    VariantInit(&var);
    var.vt = VT_UI4;
    var.ulVal = eAVEncCommonRateControlMode_Quality;
    winrt::check_hresult(encoder->SetValue(&CODECAPI_AVEncCommonRateControlMode, &var));
    var.ulVal = 70;
    winrt::check_hresult(encoder->SetValue(&CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQuality, &var));

    winrt::check_hresult(sinkWriter->BeginWriting());
    session.StartCapture();

    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

    Sleep(1000);

    session.Close();
    sinkWriter->Flush(0);
    sinkWriter->Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Do you need to use MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink ? 

I usually use MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL  and then the URL specified is a filename.

Using MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL would simplify your code some, but might not fix the problem,  try it and see if you still get the invalid parameter HRESULT.

Comment: Also looking at your code,  I think you have the MP4 profile in the input type,  Media foundation might be complaining about that  MF_MT_MPEG2_PROFILE

Comment: I think I see why you are using a media sink,  to try using MF_MPEG4SINK_MOOV_BEFORE_MDAT ?   I've never seen this attribute work, but haven't tried it recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to track down the problem. The above code had two issues:

1. Need to call `SetCurrentLength()` on the IMFMediaBuffer object. It seems silly since the way to get the length is to get the IMF2DBuffer interface from the IMFMediaBuffer object and call `GetContiguousLength()`, but it works.
2. Taking the texture straight from the `OnFrameArrived()` callback and passing it into the IMF sink is also wrong. This will exhaust the framepool (which is declared as having 2 frames) and hang the encoder. One possible solution is to copy the data out into a new texture before passing it to the encoder.

Comment: Apparently, for Hardware Encoding you need to pass the `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_VIDEO_SUPPORT` flag to `D3D11CreateDevice` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfobjects/nn-mfobjects-imfdxgidevicemanager